# How to add running total using complex if statement in Python

Tags: python

I have the following data in a text file.

```
Intium II,2.8,24,128
Celerisc I,1.6,32,256
Ethloan III,2.6,32,128
Powerup II,1.9,64,512
Mitduo III,3.1,24,128
```

I am doing the following:

**Allocating points to each processor**

Points will be awarded to each processor as follows:

- Clock speed is less than 2 GHz, award 10 points.
- Clock speed is between 2 GHz and 3 GHz inclusive, award 20 points.
- Clock speed is greater than 3 GHz, award 30 points.

**Data Bus Points**

1 point for each line on the data bus e.g. 24 bit data bus, award 24 points.

**Cache Size Points**

1 point for each whole 10 Kb of cache e.g. 128Kb cache, award 12 points.
(128/10 = 12·8, which should be rounded down to 12)

**The output from the program should be similar to the following:**

```
John Doe your order code is JD3f

    Processor    Points
    Intium II    56
    Celerisc I   67
    Ethloan III  64
    Powerup II   125
    Mitduo III   66
```

**Here is my code**

```
import random
import string

def getDetails():

  forename = input("Enter first name: ")
  surname = input("Enter last name: ")
  number = random.randint(0,9)
  character = random.choice(string.ascii_letters).lower()

  code = (forename[:1] + str(surname[:1]) + str(number) + str(character))

  return forename, surname, code

def readProcessorDetails():

  processorName = []*5
  clockSpeed = []*5
  dataBusWidth = []*5
  cacheSize = []*5

  file = open("processors.txt","r")

  for line in file:

    data = line.split(",")

    processorName.append(data[0])
    clockSpeed.append(float(data[1]))
    dataBusWidth.append(data[2])
    cacheSize.append(data[3])
  
  input("file read successfully.. Press any key to continue")

  return processorName, clockSpeed, dataBusWidth, cacheSize


def allocatePoints(clockSpeed, dataBusWidth, cacheSize):
  
  proPoints = 0.0

  processorPoints = []

  for counter in range(len(clockSpeed)):

    if clockSpeed[counter] < 2.0 or dataBusWidth[counter] == 24 or dataBusWidth[counter] == 128:
      proPoints = proPoints + 10 + 24 + 12
      processorPoints.append(proPoints)
      
    elif clockSpeed[counter] > 2.0 or clockSpeed[counter] <= 3.0 or dataBusWidth[counter] == 24 or dataBusWidth[counter] == 128:
      proPoints = proPoints + 20 + 24 + 12
      processorPoints.append(proPoints)
      
    elif clockSpeed[counter] > 3.0 or dataBusWidth[counter] == 24 or dataBusWidth[counter] == 128:
      proPoints = proPoints + 30 + 24 + 12
      processorPoints.append(proPoints)

  return processorPoints

def display(processorName, processorPoints):

  print(f"Processor \t Points")

  for counter in range(len(processorPoints)):

    print(f"{processorName[counter]}\t {processorPoints[counter]}\n")

def main():

  forename, surname, code = getDetails()
  processorName, clockSpeed, dataBusWidth, cacheSize = readProcessorDetails()
  processorPoints = allocatePoints(clockSpeed, dataBusWidth, cacheSize)
  print()
  print(forename + " " + surname + " your order code is " + code)
  print()
  display(processorName, processorPoints)
 
main()
```

**Here is my code output**

```
Enter first name: John
Enter last name: Doe
file read successfully.. Press any key to continue

John Doe your order code is JD8z

Processor    Points
Intium II    56.0

Celerisc I   102.0

Ethloan III  158.0

Powerup II   204.0

Mitduo III   260.0
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong in my allocatePoints() function where I have used complex if statements and running total to add processor points.

Comment: what exactly does each item in the text file mean?

Comment: The data on the five processors which should be used in testing. The data in order is Processor Name, Clock Speed, Data Bus Width and Cache size.

Comment: Your issue is that you never reset proPoints after a loop

Comment: And you should change your structure to store data per processor rather than per clock speed, data bus width, and cache size.

Comment: You can't do the the three criteria in one `if` statement.  You'll need separate `if` statements for each criteria.

Comment: Taking points from drum and Tim, I will use two more parallel arrays to store data and also use separately if statements. Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider keeping all of the data in one list, rather than trying to coordinate multiple lists.  This lets you avoid the unPythonic "for x in range(len(x))" construct, and iterate through the list directly.

I also fixed your root problem, which is that you weren't resetting the points to zero for every new processor.

```
import random
import string

def getDetails():
  forename = input("Enter first name: ")
  surname = input("Enter last name: ")
  number = random.randint(0,9)
  character = random.choice(string.ascii_letters).lower()

  code = (forename[:1] + str(surname[:1]) + str(number) + str(character))

  return forename, surname, code

def readProcessorDetails():

  pdata = []

  for line in  open("processors.txt"):
    data = line.split(",")
    pdata.append( [data[0], float(data[1]), int(data[2]), int(data[3])] )

  return pdata

def allocatePoints(pdata):

  for row in pdata:
      points = 0
      if row[1] < 2.0:
          points += 10
      elif row[1] <= 3.0:
          points += 20
      else:
          points += 30

      points += row[2]
      points += row[3] // 10
      row.append( points )

def display(pdata):

  print("Processor\tPoints")

  for row in pdata:

    print(f"{row[0]}\t{row[-1]}")

def main():

  forename, surname, code = getDetails()
  processorData = readProcessorDetails()
  allocatePoints(processorData)
  print()
  print(forename + " " + surname + " your order code is " + code)
  print()
  display(processorData)
 
main()
```